# Can the following materials be used to power up an attendance based sensor?

Tags: arduino-uno, sd-card, rfid

arduino uno, esp8266, rfid module rc522, sd card module, real time clock module, buzzer, led light and battery holder. I was planning to build a sensor that monitors attendance with the use of and RFID card, and I was planning to make it run on its own with the help of a battery instead of being connected to a computer. If not, is there another way that would be possible?

Comment: you only need a power supply to power up a sensor ... if you want to read data from the sensor, then you need a power supply,  an arduino and a sensor.... if you want to store the resulting data, then you need to add an SD card module ... if you want to add functionality, then you need to add a module for that functionality

Comment: start development with power supply, arduino and sensor

Comment: Possible? Yes, totally possible. You won't get really better answers with such a broad question. If this question is mainly about power, then we would need to know, what type of battery you want to use and also how you want to connect it (and everything else, since the Uno is 5V and an ESP is 3.3V)

Comment: I'm really new to this so I don't have much knowledge. I was thinking of using a 2 AA batteries connected to a battery holder to power it up because I heard that it would help it last long.

Comment: or using a 9 volt battery